# Individual zip files for folders - Excluding few

Tags: bash, shell-script

There are multiple directories under "home" directory.
dir1
dir2
dir3
dir4
dir5

I want bash script to recursively archive dir1-2-3 as dir1.zip, dir2.zip & dir3.zip but **exclude** dir4 and dir5.

Is it doable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Linux removed that feature with the latest release.

Only joking, of course it's doable.

```
for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3; do
    zip -r "$dir" "$dir"
done
```

If the directories truly have the same prefix:

```
for dir in dir[1-3]; do
    zip -r "$dir" "$dir"
done
```

This assumes that the loop is performed in the correct directory.

If you have many many directories and only want to exclude a few, use `bash` with its `extglob` shell option set:

```
shopt -s extglob
for dir in dir!(4|5); do
   test -d "$dir" || continue
   zip -r "$dir" "$dir"
done
```

The pattern `dir!(4|5)` will match any name starting with `dir` and then continuing with anything not a `4` or a `5`.  The pattern could also have been written `dir!([4-5])` or `!(dir4|dir5)`.

I've also made sure, in the last loop, that any matched name that is not the name of a directory is skipped.

Comment: Is it possible to Exclude instead of Include ? There are about 50 directories to archive and 3-4 to exclude.

Comment: use `for dir in $(ls | grep -Ev '^(dir4|dir5)$'); do ...`

Comment: @Dhillon See update.

Comment: @MichaelDaffin Does not work for all possible names.

Comment: @Kusalananda dir4, dir5 were just example. Could you please post how to exclude if directories are named as "first, second and third". Regards,

Comment: @Dhillon `!(first|second|third)`

Comment: If you like, you could use `for dir in dir!(4|5)/` ... (adding a trailing slash) to force the glob to directories-only, saving the `test` test.